# Find the smallest number which when multiplied to N makes it a multiple of M

Tags: c++

I'm doing a challenge from Dcoder called "[Simple multiple problem](https://code.dcoder.tech/challenges/5e08a9dda1312802b296d21a/simple-multiple-problem)". When I run my code in IDE everything seems to work properly, but when I submit my solution to Dcoder, it shows that all test cases are failed. Can someone review my code and suggest anything?

**Here is a problem description:**

You are given 2 numbers N and M. You have to find the smallest number which when multiplied to N makes it a multiple of M.

**Input:**

First line contains T, number of test cases.
Each of the next T lines contains two numbers, N and M.

**Output:**

For each test case, print the required answer.

**Constraints:**

1 <= T <= 100
1 <= N, M <= 10^6

**Sample Input:**

```
2
4 7
18 6
```

**Sample Output:**

```
7
1
```

My code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void find_smallest_number(int T, int **arr, int ans[]){
    for (int i=0; i<T; i++){
        for(int k=1; ; k++){
            if ((arr[i][0]*k) % arr[i][1] == 0){
                ans[i] = k;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void clearMemory(int **arr, int T){
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++){
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete [] arr;
}

int main(){
    int T;
    //cout << "T = ";
    cin >> T;
    int ans[T];
    int **arr = new int *[T];
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int [2];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<T; i++){
        //cout << "Case " << i+1 << ":\n";
        //cout << "N = ";
        cin >> arr[i][0];
        //cout << "M = ";
        cin >> arr[i][1];
    }

    find_smallest_number(T,arr,ans);

    for (int i=0; i<T; i++){
        cout << ans[i] << endl;
    }
    
    clearMemory(arr,T);
}
```

My Input (for T=4)

```
T = 4
Case 1:
N = 4
M = 7
Case 2:
N = 18
M = 6
Case 3:
N = 3
M = 21
Case 4:
N = 54
M = 4
```

With commented code the input looks like this

```
4
4
7
18
6
3
21
54
4
```

My Output

```
7
1
7
2
```

Comment: My output fot T=2 mutches the original output - just look at first two lines of the output, it's the same. I just showed another case with T=4

Comment: Don't use C-style artrays, C++ has `std::vector`. Then don't even use vector, just print the answer for each test case. And I believe the answer is simply `m / std::gcd(m, n)`.

Comment: Note that your code could be a lot simpler, there's no need to use the arrays, just read the two values, calculate the result and print the result for those values. Also note that there's no need to iterate through all the multiples of `N`, you just need to find the [lcm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lcm) then divide by `M`

Comment: @EricPostpishil its combination of misreading the post and edits that made the comment obsolte ;)

Comment: This is a maths problem, not a search problem.

Comment: @AlanBirtles lcm did the trick, thanks. int main() reduced to 8 lines. But Dcoder doesn't recognize Numeric library(.
EricPostpischil, I made some edits to the original post to clarify the problem after 463035818_is_not_a_numbe's comment